# Problems with updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem with updating Android Studio to the newer Android Studio 4.0 version. 
Everytime I want to Update my Software I get the following error: [image: Error Image]
It looks like I have a problem with access, how can I solve this problem, do I have to reinstall Android Studio?

Thanks for any help

Comment: [Have you tried this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083125/android-studio-update-issue-with-jre-bin-java)

Comment: Thank you, this helped my solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type the command

```
ps -A |grep java
```

Kill the process with

```
kill -9 YOURPROCESSID
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is Java is running and thus causing a conflict with installation.

**Ubuntu/Linux** [(Via AskUbuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083125/android-studio-update-issue-with-jre-bin-java):

> **Kill the Java process:**
>
> `ps -A |grep java`
>
> The output of this command will give you the list of java processes running on your system. Note down Process ID (PID) of which belongs to the Java process and run:
> `kill -9 PID`

**Windows:**

Kill the `java.exe` process via Task Manager, or via the command prompt:

```
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```